# ECLIPSE OXYGEN: An error has ocurred. See the log file on .metadata/.log

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Can someone help me with this? some people say you can fix this problem by deleting metadata folder but it resets a lot of configurations and to be honest i dont remember how to confing some things back to work properly on some projects, can someone identify the problem if i leave the .log text? because i dont understand whats the problem is

https://imgur.com/a/0TSbzJO

im looking for a solution to not delete the whole folder since i dont know how to restore some configurations back on the project i want to run, its an old one

Comment: Do not use images for text information in Stackoverflow. Specifically for this question, paste the log in the question.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer Eclipse Oxygen is 7 years and 23 releases old - time to move to a current release.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `.metadata` folder is almost always the **wrong** thing to do. This is pretty simple, though--Oxygen was the 2017 release, before Java 9 released, and Java releases since then have removed APIs from the Java standard runtime--including the one you're seeing errors about. As this is a release from **nearly 7 years ago**, just go get the current one from https://download.eclipse.org instead.